# Is it possible to change the format of my blog navigation?

Tags: css, navigation, blogs

I'm trying to change the style blog navigation style on [my blog](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/blog/) from "Newer / Older" text to NEXT / PREVIOUS and also make it match the same color/font/style/hover of my RSS text at the top :Subscribe via RSS: So far I can't get anything to change.

```
.pagination .next-item { color: #0076a9 !important; font-size: 8em; font-weight: 700; }
.pagination .prev-item { color: #0076a9 !important; font-size: 8em; font-weight: 700; }
```

Comment: You can definitely do it, but those words will be buried in a template somewhere. What CMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty janky way to do it, but if you ONLY have control over the CSS, this should work for you:

```
.pagination
{
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0)
}

.pagination a
{ 
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Regular", "Helvetica Neue Regular", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-weight: 700;
}

.pagination a:first-child
{
    position: relative;
    left: 616px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.pagination a:first-child:after
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: "Next";
    color: #0076a9;
}

.pagination a + a,
.pagination a:only-child
{
    position: relative;
    left: auto;
    margin-left: -59px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.pagination a + a:after,
.pagination a:only-child:after
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    content: "Previous";
    color: #0076a9;
}
```

Again, this is NOT the recommended solution, if you have control over HTML. What this does:

1. Hides the "/" from the Older/Newer
2. Sets the link font styles.
3. If there is a link in the .pagination div that is the first element (`first-child`), we assume it is the "Newer" link. We reposition that to the very right side of the page, but make the link invisible using `rgba(0,0,0,0)`
4. We utilize the CSS `:after` pseudo-class to add text after that link, which says "Next", and color it to be the same color as the link. We position that on top of the invisible link using `position: absolute` and `left: 0`
5. If there is a second link, or if there is only one link in .pagination, then we assume that is the "Older" link, and move it to the far left.
6. We then treat it the same way as the "Newer" link, but we add "Previous" to it.

Comment: It sort of worked, however I can add in html or java into the page header code injection. will that work better? @Jake

Comment: If you can modify the HTML that is already on the page, that would be best. Anything else would be just about as bad as this.

Comment: i cant modify the existing, I can only add or add something to override it.

Comment: It seamed to affect my entire blog, text, so i had to change back to the stock.

Comment: I only tested it on the pages you had linked, so yes, it may have affected other pages.

Comment: is there an easier html override?

Comment: There isn't really any such thing as an "HTML override". You could do it using javascript, but there'd be a content flash as it changes link names (it'd show the links as they are now before the fix runs)